# UITableView Delete Row

Tags: swift, tableview, uitableview

I am making a table view and I want to make a function where you can delete a row by swiping right and tapping the delete button. Me and my teacher have tried for about half an hour to fix this problem but nothing seems to work.

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var StoredValues = Values()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {//
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "meunSegue", sender: self)

        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            _ = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        }
    }
    func tableView->(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowsAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES
    }
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView committEditStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)
    func tableView {
        var cell = UITableView.self
        var Animation = UITableViewRowAnimation(rawValue: 1)
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
            cell.deleteRows(indexPath)
            //cell.deleteRows(at: [NSIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

        }
    }


    class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

        var recievedData = ""
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            print(recievedData)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your source code is an odd mix of Swift and Objective-C.  You might clean up your sample code so that it compiles and edit your question with better code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `numberOfRowsInSection` data source implementation always returns 1 (fixed).

Typically, you store objects in an array, which defines the number of rows. And, `commitEditingStyle` should remove the object from the array and then delete the row.

```
– (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
       // Delete the row from the data source
       [maTheData removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
       // Delete row using the cool literal version of [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]

       [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
}
```

Follow this [link](http://www.colejoplin.com/2012/10/05/ios-tutorial-editing-tableviews/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This swift function can delete a row by swiping right and tapping the delete button. Actually this function delete item from items array then delete row. In addition this row removed from `tableView`.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        // your items include cell variables
        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }
}
```